# Know what file will be loaded by a string in python

Tags: python

I have a string, say

```
'foo.bar.module'
```

I'd like to know which file would be loaded if I do

```
import foo.bar.module
```

but I don't want to load it. I need a function like

```
fileName = findModuleFile('foo.bar.module')
```

Comment: Is this for Python 2 or 3? In Python 3, you can use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) for such functionality, in Python 2 you'd have to re-implement much of the same (e.g. search the module search path yourself).

Comment: Python 2, but I'll move to 3, it's the logical step. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find out how to do it with importlib...

Comment: Ended up doing it with 'importlib.import_module' + 'module.__file__', the overhead is negligible.

Comment: Yes, that's probably just easier. You can't really locate modules inside packages (especially with full support for namespace packages) without loading the parent package anyway it seems. [`imp.find_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) certainly won't find nested names until the parent path has been loaded.